# innerHTML missing when XML parsing with jQuery in IE9 but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, innerhtml, jquery-xml

I'm using jQuery's XML parser on some simple content that contains HTML.

Extracting the full HTML text using jQuery's `.html()` or standard javascript `.innerHTML` works fine in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer 9. jQuery's `.text()` works in both cases, but I need the html tags extracted as well.

How can I make it work with IE9 as well?

You can test it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/199vLsgz/

XML:

```
<script id="xml_data" type="text/xml">
    <model_data name="The model ">
          <person_responsible></person_responsible>
          <objects>
               <object name="Available B reports" id="obj1" >
                   <description>this is a description <br/> oh look, another line!</description>
               </object>
          </objects>
     </model_data>
</script>
```

Code:

```
$(function() {

    var xml = $("#xml_data").text();
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);

    var desc = $xml.find("model_data > objects > object[id='obj1'] > description");
    alert(desc.html());

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xml elements do not have innerHTML defined inside IE which is what's being used with the html function of jquery.

[Firstly you need to use CDATA to preserve tags inside xml tags](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

`<description><![CDATA[this is a description <br/> oh look, another line!]]></description>`

then you can try to use the textContent property:

```
alert(desc[0].textContent); //desc.text() will also work now
```

And you also can add the content correctly using something like:

```
$('#some-container').html(desc[0].textContent);
```

```js
$(function() {

    var xml = $("#xml_data").text();
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    console.log($xml)
    var desc = $xml.find("model_data > objects > object[id='obj1'] > description");
    alert(desc[0].textContent);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="xml_data" type="text/xml">
    <model_data name="The model">
          <person_responsible></person_responsible>
          <objects>
               <object name="Available B reports" id="obj1" >
                   <description><![CDATA[this is a description <br/> oh look, another line!]]></description>
               </object>
          </objects>
     </model_data>
</script>
```